# Apps minimizing randomly

Tags: android-management-api

We have many phones using Android Management with kioskCustomLauncherEnabled on. When opening applications occasionally they will minimize as if the home button was pressed. We've observed this on Pixel 1, Pixel 3a and Pixel 4a phones. We've disabled all gestures thinking that might be related but it still occurs.

Is this a bug of the phone's kiosk mode? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a Pixel 3A problem. One of the recent system updates a few months ago seems to have made the problem go away. Doesn't appear to still be an issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and thanks for your question,

I think it's a bit difficult to answer without looking at your dedicated device policy. I haven't heard personally of such a bug but maybe it could be a behaviour you set on your policy? Generally, you would use `kioskCustomLauncherEnabled` if a device requires users to access one or more apps from the home screen triggering a go back to home type of behaviour while `keyguardDisabled` would trigger the device to stay unlocked. You will also want to disable a maximum amount of settings available to the user.

Theo L

Android Enterprise